# How to pass value from parent activity to child activity and on child activity exit, refresh the parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 3 activity.

1. Main window 5 buttons
2. From main window on button press this window open (calling it as parent)
3. On parent window button press this window open calling it as the end child window.

Now from child window I get value from parent window as below:

```
    // Set - from Window1
    Intent MyRotationsAddPicture1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyRotationsAddPicture.class);
    MyRotationsAddPicture1.putExtra("Title", "1");
    MyRotationsAddPicture1.putExtra("Content", "2");               
    startActivity(MyRotationsAddPicture1);

    // Get - from Window2
    Log.d(TAG, getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title"));
    // Workout and exit this Window2 > to go back Window1 and show the latest update on window1
    this.finish(); 
    System.exit(0);
```

But now, after working out on child window, I exit this and go back to my previous parent window. Once I go there, how can I refresh my imageView which have been modified and need to show the latest image in parent window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WIndow1:

Start your child activity as

```
Intent MyRotationsAddPicture1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyRotationsAddPicture.class);
    MyRotationsAddPicture1.putExtra("Title", "1");
    MyRotationsAddPicture1.putExtra("Content", "2");               
    startActivityForResult(MyRotationsAddPicture1, 0);
```

Override:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

In window 2:

```
// Get - from Window2
    Log.d(TAG, getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title"));
    // Workout and exit this Window2 > to go back Window1 and show the latest update on window1
setResult(0);
    this.finish();
```

> protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode,
>   Intent data)
>
> Added in API level 1 Called when an activity you launched exits,
>   giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it
>   returned, and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be
>   RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't
>   return any result, or crashed during its operation.